# How to login using by cURL in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, github, curl

How to login to Github with a request (cURL) using login and password and get an access token.
I want to do it in Laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider [`GrahamCampbell/Laravel-GitHub`](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-GitHub) which integrates [`KnpLabs/php-github-api`](https://github.com/KnpLabs/php-github-api) into Laravel.

It does include an [authorization API wrapper](https://github.com/KnpLabs/php-github-api/blob/9c57106b7ba55c17d0a2d9a6e7cef4cd4c637e4d/doc/authorizations.md), which should make you able to list/get back access tokens.